# Передать число в функцию которое больше 16 симловов

Tags: jquery

```js
function select(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
      select(1808625756245484930);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`console.log` возвращает `1808625756245485000` , хотя должен возвращать `1808625756245484930`, как бороться?

Comment: Вы вышли за пределы точности чисел в javascript, бороться никак

Comment: вообще никак???

Comment: Угу, вообще никак

Comment: что Вы измеряете такими числами, что Вам важна такая относительная точность?

Comment: ID элементов, функция select выделяет предмет, и пушит его в массив. Выглядит вот так: http://f5.s.qip.ru/GjeazU6X.png

Comment: id элементов это обычно строки, зачем вам именно числа?

Comment: сколько у Вас элементов, что Вам нужны такие `ID`? Используйте строки.

Comment: id генерирую не я. Я их получаю из api запроса. Это уникальный идентификатор предмета.

Comment: И api вам возвращает именно число что ли?

Comment: апи возвращает массив с предметами, в котором как раз таки находятся и идентификаторы

Comment: @kiLLro я не верю, что там идентификаторы не строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте число как строку

```js
function select(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
      select("1808625756245484930");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```